# Construction on Mumbai's Marine Drive

Tags: event-based-effects, mumbai

We are planning to go to Mumbai in about 3 weeks and looking at accommodation on [Marine Drive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marine_Drive,_Mumbai) (probably around Churchgate). Apparently there is a massive multi-year construction in the area called "[Mumbai Coastal Road Project](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coastal_Road_(Mumbai))".

Does anyone know if, where and how Marine Drive is affected by this at the moment? Can you access the waterfront and is there a lot of construction noise ?

Thanks !